# Retrofit: lowercase headers

Tags: android, http-headers, retrofit, retrofit2

I would like to upload a file with Retrofit. But I have to send my request with lowercase headers.

I tried to override headers but without any effect:

```
@Multipart
@PUT
fun uploadFile(
    @Url url: String,
    @Header("content-type") contentType: String,
    @Header("content-disposition") contentDisposition: String,
    @Header("content-length") contentLength: String,
    @Part file: MultipartBody.Part
): Completable
```

Retrofit log :

`D/OkHttp: Content-Type: image/jpeg
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 755543
D/OkHttp: content-disposition: inline; filename=IMG-20190502-WA0000.jpeg`

I want content-type & content-length instead of Content-Type & Content-Length

Thanks in advance

Comment: Http headers are [case insensitive](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2). Sounds like you need to fix something on the server side. Why do you need them to be lowercased?

Comment: Because the server compares the signature with lowercased headers :/

Comment: ok, but then you should calculate the signature on your side also with lowercased headers. The server maybe should also lower case everything. In the end, adding this to OkHttp sounds wrong since it doesn't follow the standard. To be honest, OkHttp might even just send the headers as you add them and what you're seeing is just the result of the logging, where headers are up cased.